# A way to use Openssl in different languages/platforms

Tags: java, c, openssl, cryptography

Openssl is known to be a standard in crypto world. Openssl is written in pure C, so the problem comes that how to use Opnessl in different languages? such Java. Though Java provides `JCE` and `BouncyCastle`, it's hard to know whether they have implementation deviations, i.e., for same input(legal or invalid), JCE and Openssl output different results.

What I come up with so far is to invoke openssl command directly. In real products, how to solve this problem?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Use the [library(ies)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/), not the command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL is using standardized algorithms, this means that no matter which library you use, the decryption result for the same key and algorithm will be the same.

**For example:**
If you take a BlowFish encryption algorithm with the key "I am a blowfish", and encrypt it with OpenSSL, you can use any library you want to decrypt it and get the same result.

Having said that, it IS possible to use OpenSSL libraries (usually libcrypto and libssl) in any language or OS. It does require some piping though.
In your example, you can use JNI to access OpenSSL library functions directly.
This approach requires that you make sure you have the right libraries for your target architecture and OS.

Personally? ***I'd see check why there are deviations as that is your main problem.***

Comment: e.g, even for simple algorithms such as Base64, JVM in PC behaves differently from Android. (someone has posted this issue in Stackoverflow).  I'd prefer that both clients and server use same crypto library to avoid potential "deviations".

Comment: Then by all means - use the same libraries. Just make sure you use the right libs for your architecture. Do you know how to use jni?

Comment: ,. thanks, I will try JNI binding for openssl. Hope JNI would not be complex

Comment: Can you provide the link to where you saw different behavior in the encryption libraries?

Answer (score 0):

> how to use Opnessl in different languages? such Java.

- In Java use **JNI**. It can be very fast. Pay attention to JNI notion of “pinning” -  the native method receives a direct pointer to the elements - without copying - but this has some implications. Pinning is optional. To use JNI one should usually create wrapper functions to invoke target functions (OpenSSL in our case). So you should create shared library (DLL or so) according to JNI rules (argument types jint, etc) and call OpenSSL function.
- It depends on language - in general in managed languages you should wrap C code (in COM or Managed C++ for example to use in .NET). In C++ - directly. C# also has mechanism of invoking C functions.

Comment: thanks for the answer. JNI is capable of executing C code, but I'm  not sure I have to modify source code of openssl. I prefer to find a "quick" way to execute openssl in Java; though executing shell is quick, I have no control of exceptions.

Comment: Updated - You should not change OpenSSL code - create wrapper. It's not difficult.